# Como abrir um link web em um botão java?

Tags: java

Bom, eu criei uma classe :

---

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.net.URI;


public class AbrirLink {
public static void main(String[] args){

    try{
        URI link = new URI("www.google.com");
        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(link);
    }catch(Exception erro){
            System.out.println(erro);
        }
    }

}
```

---

Queria saber como eu faço pra chamar ela dentro de um botão, pra daí quando eu clicar no botão abri a página web.

### Criei um ActionPerformed no Botão e coloquei o seguinte código:

```
AbrirLink ab = new AbrirLink();
```

Porém acho que falta fazer mais alguma coisa, poderiam me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desse jeito aqui funcionou:
Se quiserem abrir um link ao clicar em um item do ***JMenuBar*** basta criar um evento de ***MouseClicked*** nesse item  e colocar esse Código lá:

`String[] args;
        try{
            URI link = new URI("www.google.com");
            Desktop.getDesktop().browse(link);
        }catch(Exception erro){
            System.out.println(erro);
        }`

Caso quiserem que um ***JButtom*** abra um link ao clicar nele, crie uma ação de ***ActionPerformed*** no Botão e coloque o código acima.

Comment: Isso ai foi o que eu falei pra você fazer...  `URI link = new URI("www.google.com"); Desktop.getDesktop().browse(link);`

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o método `browse(URI uri)` da `class Desktop`!

Este método inicia o navegador padrão para exibir um `URI` **(SIMILAR A UMA URL)**.

**Exemplo:**

```
String valor = tableLinks.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse( new java.net.URI( "http://www." + valor  ));
```

**NOTA**

> Para mais informações acesse a [documentação oficial da oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html).

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, tipo eu usei esse browse(URI) e esse get Desktop ali na classe que eu fiz, até que se eu executar somente essa classe ele abre o navegador normalmente, eu queria saber se tipo tem como eu chamar essa classe no meu botão para ao clicar nele abrir o link da web, se sim, que comando eu devo fazer na ação do meu botão para conseguir executar essa classe ao clicar no botão ? Obrigado desde já

Comment: Na verdade fiz uns testes aqui e consegui, não estava dando certo pq eu estava colocando em um "botão do JMenuBar" e não um botão normal, vlw

Comment: @Vinicius tudo bem, posta o código aí pra gente na sua resposta.

Comment: Blza, coloquei ai